# Spotlight importer: how to hide the actual file name?

Tags: macos, cocoa, spotlight, spotlight-plugin

I have a Mac shoebox app with a custom data format. I'd like to add Spotlight support.

From what I read, the recommendation seems to be to define a custom UTI file type and create one file of that type for each "record" in my app as a reference to the actual "record" that my app can then make sense of when the user clicks on a search result.

So far so good. My custom Spotlight importer works and indexes my "reference" files. They show up in Spotlight.

However, the file name reveals that this is my custom "reference" file. From a user's perspective that does not make sense.

Is there a way to hide or replace what is shown as file name and path in Spotlight?

Also, if a users presses Command while clicking on the search result, the file is revealed in Finder. In my case in the `Library/Caches/Metadata/MyApp` folder. That's not what I want… I don't want users to see this folder, because it reveals internals about the app.

[image: Spotlight result]

**EDIT:**
In a way, my app is similar to a Core Data app with a database, only that I'm using a custom data format. With Core Data, the user also does not see the actual database file.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a value for kMDItemDisplayName

Comment: I did. This only has an effect on the title shown in the primary result list (cut off in my screenshot).

Comment: I also tried kMDItemFSName, kMDItemPath, and kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden, no luck...

Comment: Just checked what the preview for an Evernote note looks like. It shows the file name of the proxy file.